# What is the most efficient way to calculate a huge sparse diagonal correlation matrix?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, correlation, bigdata

I have a huge correlation matrix that I need to calculate, say *200000x200000*, which is too large to store in memory.  Luckily, most of the values are 0s, except for values close to the diagonal of the matrix, which I need to calculate.  Hence, I'm curious if sparse matrices in scipy/numpy could help me speed things up.

The current way that I construct the data is as follows.

```
#Input variables are snps, and max_dist
num_snps, num_indivs = snps.shape    
corr_table = {}
for i in range(num_snps):
    corr_table[i] = {}

for i in range(0, num_snps - 1):
    start_i = i + 1
    end_i = min(start_i + max_dist, num_snps)
    corr_vec = sp.dot(snps[i], sp.transpose(snps[start_i:end_i])) / float(num_indivs)
    corr_vec = sp.array(corr_vec).flatten()
    for k in range(start_i, end_i):
        corr_vec_i = k - start_i
        corr_table[i][k] = corr_vec[corr_vec_i]
        corr_table[k][i] = corr_vec[corr_vec_i]
return corr_table
```

Here **snps** is a *MxN* matrix with standardised row-vectors (mean 0 and variance 1), for which I'd like to calculate the *MxM* correlation matrix. Currently the correlation matrix is stored as a huge dictionary (**corr_table**).  The **max_dist** denotes the maximum distance between the a pair of SNPs (rows in the **snps** matrix) for which I calculate the correlation.  For all other correlations (that are not in the **corr_table**) I assume they are 0.

Unfortunately, this is still not very efficient in practice, hence, I'd like to know if I can use matrix multiplications together with sparse matrices to calculate the correlation matrix more efficiently without using much more memory.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried to understand or run your calculation, but I can add some pointers about sparse matrices.

There are a half dozen different sparse `formats` in the package, each with different strengths and weaknesses. And it is easy to convert one format to another; the sparse functions do that frequently.  None are very good for incremental updating.

The `dok` format is actually a dictionary subclass.  The keys are coordinate tuples, e.g. `corr_table[(i,k)] = corr_vec[corr_vec_i]`.  I found in other SO questions that it is faster to build a plain dictionary with these keys, and then `update` the `dok` from that.  There's more overhead in the `corr_matrix[i,k]=...` indexing.

`lol` is also relatively good for incremental changes.  It stores values in 2 lists of lists, one sublist per row of the matrix.

`csr` is good for matrix calculations, but slow for indexed assignments.  It is best built with the `coo` style of input, which uses 3 1d arrays, `data`, `i`,`j`.  Traditionally sparse matrices have been built by constructing these 3 arrays, possibly as lists if doing it incrementally, and then passing them to `coo_matrix`.

There are block and diagonal formats as well, which may be better for some sparsity layouts.

I suspect this step:

```
for k in range(start_i, end_i):
    corr_vec_i = k - start_i
    corr_table[i][k] = corr_vec[corr_vec_i]
    corr_table[k][i] = corr_vec[corr_vec_i]
```

can be performed a `numpy` vector operation, something like

```
jj = np.arange(start_i, end_i)
ii = jj - start_i
data_list.append(corr_vec[ii])
row_list.append(ii)
col_list.append(jj)
data_list.append(corr_vec[ii])
row_list.append(jj)
col_list.append(ii)
```

where `data_list` etc are lists where I am collecting inputs for `coo`.  They probably will have to be passed through `np.concatenate` to produce 1d arrays that `sparse.coo_matrix` can use.

I haven't tested this code so there are bugs, but hopefully it gives you some ideas to start with.